# Removing Null title/string from infoWindow of CartoDB?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I am new to using CartoDB.

My issue stems from having multiple data columns displayed in the infowindow when clicked. In this case I don't want "null" or the title if null, to appear in the infowindow - I just want the data that isn't null to appear.

Answer (score 2):

This is not that simple. You have to edit your info window html.

[image: edit the html]

Once inside the html. find the ones you want to check if their null (all of them  guess)
then add these around the `<h4>` and `<p>` tags

```
{{#columnname}}
<h4>columnname</h4>
<p>{{columnname}}</p>
{{/columnname}}
```

but it could break some formatting.
the info windows are using mustache to render the templates:
https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html